# CAS 6.1.6 get accessToken endpoint hitting 403 forbidden

Tags: cas, apereo

I am working on upgrading from CAS 5.3.3 to CAS 6.1.6. However, I am hitting HTTP 403 forbidden when I tried to POST /cas/oauth2.0/accessToken via client credentials flow. Using the same credentials, converting request to GET /cas/oauth2.0/accessToken, I am able to successfully (HTTP 200) get the access tokens.

Details are described in the following post, https://groups.google.com/a/apereo.org/forum/#!topic/cas-user/_eDaeGUj2bA

Is there something that I have missed out? any advises?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant content, not a link. The link may go stale in the future or the content may change.

Comment: Same here. Did you find the cause?